How to derive resulting PDF of a random variable transformation involving discrete and continuous random variables?
This is a communication theory question, an example from the book Foundations of MIMO Communications. Suppose a symbol $s$ is drawn from a BPSK constellation (the book says distribution, but I do not understand why?). Assuming $y=\sqrt{\rho}s+z$, where $z$ is the noise Gaussian distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Then it says that pdf of $y$ is:
$$f(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}(\exp(-{|y+\sqrt{\rho}|}^2)+\exp(-{|y-\sqrt{\rho}|}^2))$$
My understanding:
The question to which this example is a follow up assumes $s$ to be Gaussian distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, but I am confused as to how can $s$ which can only take two values be Gaussian Distributed. So, I am assuming $s$ as Bernoulli distributed with probability $1/2$ for $s=+1$ and $s=-1$. Now the very best to which I can reach is
$$f(y)=\mathcal{N}(\sqrt{\rho},1)$$ with probability $1/2$ and $$f(y)=\mathcal{N}(-\sqrt{\rho},1)$$ with probability $1/2$,
which ofcourse seems strange.
Can one explain to me how the result is derived in the book?

It is essentially that; $Y$ is an equal mixture of a $N(\sqrt{\rho},1)$ and a $N(-\sqrt{\rho},1)$. Some constants are wrong, though; the normalization is wrong and the scaling in the exponent is wrong. The latter is just a choice of parametrization really, so that's just being nonstandard, but the former makes the whole distribution not normalized.

@Ian Thanks. However, It would be of great help if you can provide a proper answer with correct distribution, so that I can get an idea.

The given pdf isn't correct regardless of whether $\ s\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)\ $ or $\ 2s-1\sim B\left(1,\frac{1}{2}\right)\ .$ In the former case, if $\ s\ $ and $\ z\ $ are independent, then $\ y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\rho+1)\ .$ In the latter case, again if $\ s\ $ and $\ z\ $ are independent, then
\begin{align}
P(y\le u\,|\,s=1)&=P(\sqrt{\rho}s+z\le u\,|\ s=1)\\
&=P(z\le u-\sqrt{\rho}\,|\,s=1)\\
&=P(z\le u-\sqrt{\rho})\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{u-\sqrt{\rho}}e^\frac{-\xi^2}{2}\,d\xi\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^ue^\frac{-(\xi+\sqrt{\rho})^2}{2}\,d\xi\ ,
\end{align}
and similarly,
$$
P(y\le u\,|\,s=-1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^ue^\frac{-(\xi-\sqrt{\rho})^2}{2}\,d\xi\ .
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
P(y\le u)&=P(y\le u\,|\,s=-1)P(s=-1)+P(y\le u\,|\,s=1)P(s=1)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^u\left(e^\frac{-(\xi-\sqrt{\rho})^2}{2}+e^\frac{-(\xi+\sqrt{\rho})^2}{2}\right)\,d\xi\right)\ ,
\end{align}
and the probability density function $\ f\ $ of $\ y\ $ is given by
$$
f(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(e^\frac{-(y-\sqrt{\rho})^2}{2}+e^\frac{-(y+\sqrt{\rho})^2}{2}\right)\ .
$$

Really grateful for providing me the real answer. Thanks!!!
